# bash remote ssh update append replace

Tags: bash, ssh, replace, append

I can successfully ssh into a remote Linux/Ubuntu machine located on a remote LAN from another Linux/Ubuntu machine located on my local LAN and I can also append the file that I want on the remote machine with my new data using example:

```
RET_IP="111.111.111.111"
HOSTNAME=system host name
PORT="111"
DEST_FILE="/etc/hosts_2"
echo "$RET_IP     $HOSTNAME" | ssh -p  $PORT root@hostname "cat >> $DEST_FILE"
```

The file contents represent an /etc/hosts file. What I can't figure out what to do is how to replace the line for the IP  hostname. There may be several entries to the hosts_2 file and even some entries with the same IP address, just different hostname and I want to locate the line with hostname"X" and replace it or if that hostname"X" doesn't exist, I want to add/append the hosts_2 file with the new line.

I do not know if this is possible remotely. Maybe it is not possible remotely. My searches have not found what I need although maybe there is something with sed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IP="111.111.111.111"
ssh_system_hostname="whatever"
new_hostname="system host name"
old_hostname="X"
port="111"
dest_file="/etc/hosts_2"
ssh -p $port root@$ssh_system_hostname -i "grep \"$IP     $old_hostname\" $dest_file
    && sed -ie \"s:$IP     $old_hostname:$IP     $new_hostname:g\" $dest_file
    || echo \"$IP     $new_hostname\" >> $dest_file"
```

Lemme know if this works. I'm not entirely sure I escaped my double quotes correctly.

Explanation: you ssh as normal, and then you check if the line exists in the file with grep. If that succeeds, you do a substitute with sed for the old thing and replace it with the new thing in that file. If the grep fails (or if the grep succeeds and somehow the sed fails), then append to the file with echo.

---

Comment: Hi Jeremy, I gave it `code`           TEST_IP="111.111.111.111"
          TEST_HOSTNAME="$HOSTNAME"
          port="222"
          IP="222.222.222.222"
          old_hostname="nanoPCT4"
          new_hostname="nanoPCT4"
          dest_file="etc/hosts_2"
          $new_hostname="Test_Host" and           ssh -p $port root@${dUSER[${x}]} -i "grep \"$TEST_IP     $old_hostname\" $dest_file
            && sed -ie \"s:$TEST_IP     $old_hostname:$IP     $new_hostname:g\" $dest_file
            || echo \"$IP     $new_hostname\" >> $dest_file" and it ssh's fine but returns this:

Comment: nanoPCT4=Test_Host: command not found
Warning: Identity file grep "111.111.111.111     nanoPCT4" /etc/hosts_2
            && sed -ie "s:111.111.111.111     nanoPCT4:222.222.222.222     nanoPCT4:g" /etc/hosts_2
            || echo "222.222.222.222     nanoPCT4" >> /etc/hosts_2 not accessible: No such file or directory.

Comment: Both of these work from the command line:               echo "333.333.333.333   nanoPCT4" >> /etc/hosts_2
          sed -ie "s:333.333.333.333   nanoPCT4:444.444.444.444   nanoPCT4:g" /etc/hosts_2

Comment: This also worked fine from the command line.   grep "111.111.111.111   nanoPCT4" /etc/hosts_2 && sed -ie "s:333.333.333.333   nanoPCT4:444.444.444.444   nanoPCT4:g" /etc/hosts_2 || echo "333.333.333.333   nanoPCT4" >> /etc/hosts_2

Comment: I was able to log in remotely using the -ssh credentials and successfully execute grep "111.111.111.111   nanoPCT4" /etc/hosts_2 && sed -ie "s:333.333.333.333   nanoPCT4:444.444.444.444   nanoPCT4:g" /etc/hosts_2 || echo "333.333.333.333   nanoPCT4" >> /etc/hosts_2  from the command line. I just can't do it all at the same time.

Comment: OK, I have it working. I needed to drop the ssh "-i" and I had to put it all on one line instead of 3 lines. Now, how can I get it to match no matter how many spaces are between the IP and the Hostname in the test file?

Comment: Got it [[:space:]]\+ = match one or more in grep

Comment: @WesZ, sorry, I was asleep. Is everything working now? Do you need any other help?